# Move a certain HTML content into another sheet on print

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I am preparing the @Media print CSS on a website that will display dynamic content. This means that the height of the content to be displayed will vary according to what the user has filled in the form.

My question is: Due to the height of the contents to be displayed can vary from case to case, is it possible to define in which content is printed in which sheet? Example  will be printed on sheet 1,  on sheet 2, and so on. The point is to make it look pretty of course because sometimes it happens that the title of an image ends up on the first sheet and the image on the sheet number 2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `page-break-before: always;`

Example:

```
@media print {
div.example {page-break-before: always;}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither page-break-before: always; or break-before:always; are working :(